# ClickOnce installing prereqs out of order

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce

I have an Outlook plugin that I am deploying using ClickOne (right click on project file, choose publish, etc...). I recently created a blank XP VM with only Office 2007 installed. My ClickOnce installer recognizes that I need my three prerequisites (Office 2007 PIAs, .Net 3.5 Sp1, and VSTO 2010 tools). They download fine but then the installer tries to install the Office 2007 PIAs first and my install fails because .Net 3.5 Sp1 and VSTO 2010 tools are prerequisites for the Office 2007 PIAs. How can I change the install order of my prerequisites? Also, are there better options for deploying ClickOnce's applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted a response to your [thread in the MSDN ClickOnce forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/98f355af-ef94-4093-a858-a0871ea72e84).